Podman build nextjs stuck in Creating an optimized production build
I'm building a linux/amd64 version of the nextjs project on my local machine on the m2 chip, but it's stuck and not moving, without any error messages or logs. This problem has been bothering me for two days now, I even suspect it's a code problem with my project, but it still does when I regenerate a new nextjs project. Has anyone had a similar problem?
 podman build --arch amd64 -t web .
[1/4] STEP 1/1: FROM node:20-alpine AS base
Resolved "node" as an alias (/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/000-shortnames.conf)
Trying to pull docker.io/library/node:20-alpine...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob sha256:ec99f8b99825a742d50fb3ce173d291378a46ab54b8ef7dd75e5654e2a296e99
Copying blob sha256:ba1057ec209ef729ee564099a0340d0b78324c97778af46879c287bc13e2ebe8
Copying blob sha256:b0691ab91e2774c9a10e06e87cd53c04d60fec055f28d158efb4768080e5beb0
Copying blob sha256:b76f83d65b1b4ebbbf1dc6c3a171a2658ebb2d3b726dbfdd7b8bfd645698f5f9
Copying config sha256:fe82994959881783fd8dd4b838559f7a3da80126d2fd6aa965b905e587e114b7
Writing manifest to image destination
--> fe8299495988
[3/4] STEP 1/5: FROM fe82994959881783fd8dd4b838559f7a3da80126d2fd6aa965b905e587e114b7 AS builder
[3/4] STEP 2/5: WORKDIR /app
--> bf7608a68b7f
[3/4] STEP 3/5: COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
[4/4] STEP 1/15: FROM fe82994959881783fd8dd4b838559f7a3da80126d2fd6aa965b905e587e114b7 AS runner
[4/4] STEP 2/15: WORKDIR /app
--> Using cache bf7608a68b7fe71ba9a81995355fc6f6cd16f442dab618fb621c1dc6b42f542c
--> bf7608a68b7f
[4/4] STEP 3/15: ENV NODE_ENV production
--> 8f2c29c78665
[4/4] STEP 4/15: RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
--> a6c3fe193f8e
[4/4] STEP 5/15: RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs
--> bd25b89454cc
[4/4] STEP 6/15: COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
[2/4] STEP 1/5: FROM fe82994959881783fd8dd4b838559f7a3da80126d2fd6aa965b905e587e114b7 AS deps
[2/4] STEP 2/5: RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/3) Installing musl-obstack (1.2.3-r2)
(2/3) Installing libucontext (1.2-r3)
(3/3) Installing gcompat (1.1.0-r4)
OK: 11 MiB in 19 packages
--> 74fa2f551d46
[2/4] STEP 3/5: WORKDIR /app
--> 0f8e1fc200f6
[2/4] STEP 4/5: COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
--> b56bcd94db83
[2/4] STEP 5/5: RUN npm ci
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead
npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/config-array@0.11.14: Use @eslint/config-array instead
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported

added 362 packages, and audited 363 packages in 16s

137 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.7.0 -> 10.8.1
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.8.1
npm notice To update run: npm install -g npm@10.8.1
npm notice
--> 90e7953c1e19
--> fe222247c093
[3/4] STEP 4/5: COPY . .
--> c8b45a59dccb
[3/4] STEP 5/5: RUN npm run build

> web@0.1.0 build
> next build

Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.4

   Creating an optimized production build ...


Containerfile
FROM node:20-alpine AS base
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN npm ci

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/next.config.mjs ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

# server.js is created by next build from the standalone output
# https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output
CMD HOSTNAME="0.0.0.0" node server.js

podman info
podman info
host:
  arch: arm64
  buildahVersion: 1.36.0
  cgroupControllers:
  - cpuset
  - cpu
  - io
  - memory
  - pids
  - rdma
  - misc
  cgroupManager: systemd
  cgroupVersion: v2
  conmon:
    package: conmon-2.1.10-1.fc40.aarch64
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.1.10, commit: '
  cpuUtilization:
    idlePercent: 82.31
    systemPercent: 0.89
    userPercent: 16.8
  cpus: 5
  databaseBackend: sqlite
  distribution:
    distribution: fedora
    variant: coreos
    version: "40"
  eventLogger: journald
  freeLocks: 2048
  hostname: localhost.localdomain
  idMappings:
    gidmap: null
    uidmap: null
  kernel: 6.8.11-300.fc40.aarch64
  linkmode: dynamic
  logDriver: journald
  memFree: 1369284608
  memTotal: 3794493440
  networkBackend: netavark
  networkBackendInfo:
    backend: netavark
    dns:
      package: aardvark-dns-1.11.0-1.20240531102943328308.main.4.g6838c50.fc40.aarch64
      path: /usr/libexec/podman/aardvark-dns
      version: aardvark-dns 1.12.0-dev
    package: netavark-1.11.0-1.20240606174759319307.main.8.gfebe31a.fc40.aarch64
    path: /usr/libexec/podman/netavark
    version: netavark 1.12.0-dev
  ociRuntime:
    name: crun
    package: crun-1.15-1.20240607090105650503.main.32.gea54402.fc40.aarch64
    path: /usr/bin/crun
    version: |-
      crun version UNKNOWN
      commit: 7cfd0aeb40e4605b6b0ee0afd9cfca80f9c5f68a
      rundir: /run/crun
      spec: 1.0.0
      +SYSTEMD +SELINUX +APPARMOR +CAP +SECCOMP +EBPF +CRIU +LIBKRUN +WASM:wasmedge +YAJL
  os: linux
  pasta:
    executable: /usr/bin/pasta
    package: passt-0^20240510.g7288448-1.fc40.aarch64
    version: |
      pasta 0^20240510.g7288448-1.fc40.aarch64-pasta
      Copyright Red Hat
      GNU General Public License, version 2 or later
        <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html>
      This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
      There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
  remoteSocket:
    exists: true
    path: /run/podman/podman.sock
  rootlessNetworkCmd: pasta
  security:
    apparmorEnabled: false
    capabilities: CAP_CHOWN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE,CAP_FOWNER,CAP_FSETID,CAP_KILL,CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE,CAP_SETFCAP,CAP_SETGID,CAP_SETPCAP,CAP_SETUID,CAP_SYS_CHROOT
    rootless: false
    seccompEnabled: true
    seccompProfilePath: /usr/share/containers/seccomp.json
    selinuxEnabled: true
  serviceIsRemote: true
  slirp4netns:
    executable: /usr/bin/slirp4netns
    package: slirp4netns-1.2.2-2.fc40.aarch64
    version: |-
      slirp4netns version 1.2.2
      commit: 0ee2d87523e906518d34a6b423271e4826f71faf
      libslirp: 4.7.0
      SLIRP_CONFIG_VERSION_MAX: 4
      libseccomp: 2.5.3
  swapFree: 0
  swapTotal: 0
  uptime: 0h 12m 49.00s
  variant: v8
plugins:
  authorization: null
  log:
  - k8s-file
  - none
  - passthrough
  - journald
  network:
  - bridge
  - macvlan
  - ipvlan
  volume:
  - local
registries:
  search:
  - docker.io
store:
  configFile: /usr/share/containers/storage.conf
  containerStore:
    number: 0
    paused: 0
    running: 0
    stopped: 0
  graphDriverName: overlay
  graphOptions:
    overlay.imagestore: /usr/lib/containers/storage
    overlay.mountopt: nodev,metacopy=on
    overlay.use_composefs: "false"
  graphRoot: /var/lib/containers/storage
  graphRootAllocated: 99252940800
  graphRootUsed: 6147694592
  graphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: xfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "false"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Supports shifting: "true"
    Supports volatile: "true"
    Using metacopy: "true"
  imageCopyTmpDir: /var/tmp
  imageStore:
    number: 11
  runRoot: /run/containers/storage
  transientStore: false
  volumePath: /var/lib/containers/storage/volumes
version:
  APIVersion: 5.1.1
  Built: 1717459200
  BuiltTime: Tue Jun  4 08:00:00 2024
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.22.3
  Os: linux
  OsArch: linux/arm64
  Version: 5.1.1


Why does the topic about podman not seem to be active at all?

The solution is that you need to additionally install the lima machine and start a qemu driven machine instead of the default rusetta machine and then everything will go smoothly.
https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions/23201#discussioncomment-11094909
